# Some App keeps crashing / can't enter the settings

Tags: crashes, google-pixel-3-xl

I have a Pixel 3 XL running Android 11 security update March 5th 2021
I get constant popups that flash for a sec saying app stopped working and goes away, I can't tell which app it is.
Other things I noticed,
The google news feed (swipe left) is gone.  I tried to go to the home settings and toggle it back on and off and it doesn't come back.  But also in the home settings if I click At a Glance it sends me to a setting screen and then kicks me back out.

The app called Google (not chrome) does not open, if I go to the settings for that app and try to clear storage, a screen pops up called Google Search Settings but then kicks me back out to the previous screen

I did a clear storage on Pixel Launcher and I wiped out my home screen, but what ever the app is it keeps crashing.

How can I determine what app is causing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

So it was actually the app called Google.  Now why you can't uninstall it from your phone, by dragging it to the top, you can go to the app info page and on the bottom of the page is a link that says installed from the Play Store.  If you click that it will take you to the play store app page.  From there I was able to uninstall and reinstall the app.  Now google search voice and news are working again.